# Is there a way to automatically preview a file when the cursor is placed over it in netrw listing?

Tags: vim

This is not about hitting ‘p’ when over the file name , but essentially having the same result by simply placing the cursor over it.

Comment: What did you find in `:help netrw`?

Comment: I found pretty much everything else,  but how to modify behaviour on cursor positioning.  If it is there,  I should probably read it again, I might have overlooked the appropriate section. Can you give some hints on specific directive or function to search for?

Comment: You didn't find it because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can remap some motions to a function that populates the preview window according to the current word under the cursor.

Here's a basic example that handles text files and directories:

```
set nocompatible
set autochdir

" Previewed files are present in the current directory
let g:netrw_keepdir = 0

function! PreviewFile(...)
    let l:wordUnderCursor = a:1
    if !empty(glob(l:wordUnderCursor))
        let l:type = system('file -ib ' . shellescape(l:wordUnderCursor))
        if l:type =~# '^text/plain'
            silent! execute 'pedit' l:wordUnderCursor
        elseif l:type =~# '^inode/directory'
            let l:name = tempname()
            set noautochdir
            silent! execute 'pedit! ' . l:name
            wincmd P
            normal! ggdG
            silent! execute 'r !ls ' . l:wordUnderCursor
            normal! ggdd
            wincmd w
        endif
    endif
endfunction

autocmd FileType netrw
            \ nnoremap j j:call PreviewFile(expand("<cWORD>"))<CR> |
            \ nnoremap k k:call PreviewFile(expand("<cWORD>"))<CR>
```